# Trying to bring back the id of an API response expected and actual match?

Tags: java, testng, rest-assured

I have been playing around testing an api I've looked for ID 24 in my test and my actual and expected are the same I'm assuming I'm using the incorrect syntax where I have .body what should I put in place instead?

```
    @Test
public void test_get_userid() {

    given().
            when().
            get("http://bpdts-test-app-v2.herokuapp.com/user/24").
            then().
            assertThat().
            statusCode(200).
            and().
            contentType(ContentType.JSON).
            and().
            body("id", equalTo("24"));
}

java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
JSON path id doesn't match.
Expected: 24
  Actual: 24
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type of id is an integer, not String.

Correct Answer is

```
given().when().get("http://bpdts-test-app-v2.herokuapp.com/user/24").then().assertThat().statusCode(200).and()
            .contentType(ContentType.JSON).and().body("id", equalTo(24));
```

You can test using the following code which will give the type of the value as "java.lang.Integer"

```
Class<? extends Object> m1 = given().when().get("http://bpdts-test-app-v2.herokuapp.com/user/24").getBody()
            .jsonPath().get("id").getClass();
    System.out.println(m1);
```

Answer (score 1):

The provided JSON object has the number `24` under the key `"id"`. It is not a JSON string, that  would be `"24"`.

Have you tried `equalTo(24)` ? As in a number literal, not a string literal.